# Multiple update query in Razor Pages .ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sqlite, web, razor

I'm trying to develop a tiny front-end for a sqlite DB using Razor Pages (NOT MVC!).

Looks like it supports SQL in a different way, not like I used to in the past.

For example, I need to re-assign value to the field Pl_Pos (position of the record in the list). Now I do this like that:

```
        for (int i = PlnPos + 1; i<= PlModelIndexModel.PlnModelTotal; i++)
        {
            PlnModel PlnModelRedo = await _context.Plane_Models.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Pl_Model_Pos == i);
            PlnModelRedo.Pl_Model_Pos = i - 1;
            _context.Attach(PlnModelRedo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Is there any other way to do it more efficient and do something like:

```
Update Pl_Models set Pl._Models.Pl_Pos = Pl_Models set Pl._Models.Pl_Pos - 1 where Pl_Models set Pl._Models.Pl_Pos > PlnPos
```

I stuck a bit...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but it sounds like
you're just after a LINQ statement or foreach loop.

```
var PlaneModels = _context.Plane_Models.ToList();
foreach(PlaneModel pm in PlaneModels)
{
PlaneModel.Pl_Model_Pos -= 1;
}
_context.Plane_Models.UpdateRange(PlaneModels);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When are you trying to modify the position of the record in the list? When a record is inserted/appended/deleted, or is it used as a display index?

Comment: I delete one record and need to re-index other records remaining in the DB. Position is stored as a field in the table